# Generic function using generic interface

Tags: typescript

I would like to infer the return type of a generic function, but it seems like TypeScript doesn't have anything to help with it.

Given the following piece of code:

```
// Generic type for object key access
export type Indexable<T = unknown> = {[key:string]:T}

// My function that does something (usually retrieve data from an API and cast to T)
const myFOO = <T extends Indexable = Indexable>(input:Indexable)=>{
    return input as T // I know this is pointless but its for simplicity sake
}

// My objects type
type MyType = { a: string }

// Invoke the function with some data and MyType
const foo = myFOO<MyType>({'a':'b'})
/*
Return type is: MyType

This is correct as it should be
*/


type MyInferredReturnType=ReturnType<typeof myFOO>
/*
MyInferredReturnType is:
{
    [key: string]: unknown;
}

This is incorrect as I have no way to provide a generic to that function without invoking it
*/
```

So then I tried to create an interface that matches the function and use that for getting the return type:

```
interface myBAR<T extends Indexable = Indexable>{
    (input:Indexable):T
}

const myBAR: myBAR = <T extends Indexable = Indexable>(input: Indexable) => {
    return input as T // I know this is pointless but its for simplicity sake
}

const bar = myBAR<MyType>({ 'a': 'b' }) //Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1.

type MyInferredBARReturnType = ReturnType<myBAR<MyType>>
 /*
MyInferredBARReturnType is:
{
    [key: string]: unknown;
}
This is incorrect as I my provided type was not passed to the function
*/
```

Then I tried to add the generic in the interface to the function which fixes the *Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1* error but `ReturnType<myBAR<MyType>>` still returns the wrong type

**UPDATE:**

There are two possible solutions to this issue but neither are perfect:

1. Create an interface with the same name but do not use the interface for the function:

_

```
// Generic type for object key access
export type Indexable<T = unknown> = { [key: string]: T }

// My objects type
type MyType = { a: string }

interface myFOO<T extends Indexable = Indexable> {
    (input: Indexable): T
}

const myFOO = <T extends Indexable = Indexable>(input: Indexable) => {
    return input as T // I know this is pointless but its for simplicity sake
}


type MyInferredReturnType = ReturnType<myFOO<MyType>>
//MyInferredReturnType is MyType

const bar = myFOO<MyType>({ 'a': 'b' }) //Expected 0 type arguments, but got 

type t = typeof bar
// t is MyType
```

My issue with this one is the lack of connection between the function and the interface.

1. Use Nadia Chibrikova's idea from the comments:

_

```
const myBAR: myFOO<MyType> = myFOO

type MyInferredBARReturnType = ReturnType<typeof myBAR>
//MyInferredBARReturnType is MyType
```

My issue with this one is I need to alias the function every time I want to change the generic type.

Is there a better way to achieve?

Comment: As you say yourself you can't know the exact return type of a generic function before invoking it, which means for your second version to work you need to define the interface and provide the concrete type to the function, so the function implements a generic interface but it is not generic itself (e.g. `const myFunc:myInterface<MyType>`, so it always returns MyType)

Comment: That could work. Not perfect but works. See update.